# jsPDF via script tag always not defined

Tags: php, undefined, jspdf

I have searched for a long time but nothing helps.
I have two files header.php and other.php.

My `header.php` it looks like this:

```
<head>
.....
</head>
<header>
.....
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.0.0/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
</header>
```

I require the `header.php` in `other.php` and want to use jsPDF in this file:

```
require "header.php";

<body>
....
</body>

<script>
    function createInvoice(final){
      const doc = new jsPDF();

      doc.text("Hello world!", 10, 10);
      doc.save("a4.pdf");
    }
</script>
```

I tried with the script to include jsPDF in the body tag, in the head tag and over the script tag with the function, but every time I am getting the following error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined
```

Can someone help me?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the new release, they changed the name of the global variable -> `const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf`.

```
<script>
    window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF; // add this line of code

    function createInvoice(final){
        const doc = new jsPDF();

        doc.text("Hello world!", 10, 10);
        doc.save("a4.pdf");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much. This is it!

Comment: Do you have per chance an idea how I can add the autotable plugin?